# iOS10:ObjectiveC didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not getting called at sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I have a problem in getting device token for a device after registering it to the push. Whenever user installs the app, I'm asking the user to register for a push if he allows then I'm not getting device token for the first time and when the closes the app and opens it again I'm getting the device token and at some times I'm not getting only. I want you to guys to give me the code for getting device token **every time** when the user opens the app. Irrespective of change of the token. My code is as follows

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
            [self registerForPushNotification];
        }

    -(void)registerForPushNotification{        
            if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"10.0")){
                UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
                center.delegate = self;
                [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound + UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
                    if(!error){
                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];                NSLog( @"Push success:: Push registration success." );
                        [Localytics didRequestUserNotificationAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound + UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) granted:granted];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog( @"Push Failed:: Push registration FAILED" );
                        NSLog( @"Push Failed:: ERROR: %@ - %@", error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedDescription );
                        NSLog( @"Push Failed:: SUGGESTIONS: %@ - %@", error.localizedRecoveryOptions, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion );
                    }
                }];
            }
        }


- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSString* deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description]
                                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""] ;
    NSLog(@"Device_Token: %@",deviceTokenString);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings // NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Comment: Add this method, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError to identify if any problem occurs while getting device token from push. Sometimes connection has problem because of poor network, at that time it fails to receive device token. just try this!

Comment: Yes, I have already added but it is not entering here. 
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Push Failed:: Failed to register for remote notifications: %@", [error description]);
}

Comment: the problem is it is entering in to center requestAuthorizationWithOptions and if no error block also it is entering and when this line comes                         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];  this also executes but not going to didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method

Comment: did you check didfinishlaunchingoptions and  registerforremotenotification method is called everytime when you open the application?

Comment: then try this one. [self registerForRemoteNotifications] in your appdelegate class.

Comment: [self registerForRemoteNotifications] it is in my app delegate class only @NandhaKumar

Comment: is it perfectly working for u in ios 10 with UNUserNotificationCenter?

Comment: can we move this over automatic chat room of stackoverflow ?

Comment: yeah its working for me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152837/discussion-between-nandhakumar-and-deepakraj-murugesan).

Comment: did you make sure provisioning profile is correct & correctly configured.

Comment: If it is not correctly configured I won't be getting device token at few times also right here the problem is I'm not getting device token 100 percent of time